# Add property to object based on parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to add properties to an object based on a parameter?

```
function add_property<Obj extends Object, Value>(
    obj: Obj,
    name: string,
    value: Value
): Obj & {name: Value} {

    obj[name] = value;
    return obj;
}
```

### Example

The idea is that `obj2` has the type `{ hello: number, bye: string }`.

```
let obj = { hello: 5 };
let obj2 = add_property(obj, "bye", "test");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function add_property<Obj extends Record<string, unknown>, Name extends string, Value>(obj: Obj, name: Name, value: Value): Obj & {[K in Name]: Value} {
    return { ...obj, [name]: value};
}
```

Example:

```
const user = { name: "Mike" };
const user2 = add_property(user, "age", 20);

// user2 has type { name: string; } & { age: number; }
```